# Interaction of Tris HCl and EDTA with Nylon

Tags: organic-chemistry

I recently learned that we're storing some of our buffers that contain Tris HCl and EDTA in nylon containers.  I can't find anything definitive but I have a suspicion that those components can interact with the nylon.  I was wondering if it is a a good idea to use nylon or if there will be significant reactivity with the components.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Chemistry.SE. Please feel free to take the short [tour] or visit the [help] if you have any questions about the site. Best of luck with your question.

Answer (score -1):

$\ce{HCl}$ itself will dissolve any nylon at room temperature, because of strong acidity ($K_\text{a} = \pu{1e6}$). When you have a mixture of $\ce{HCl}$ and EDTA, so the strength of $\ce{HCl}$ will reduced, but it also depends on the concentration of $\ce{HCl}$ in this buffer and room temperature.

If you store this buffer in nylon container, so this container can not be melted anyway, I believe, but for long term use, I recommend that you shall use other stuff to contain it.

Comment: It seems you dunno what tris is...